# How can I create an array with doctrine relations, joincolumn and ManyToOne?

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine, associations, entity

I relate two entities with `ManyToOne`:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icons")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id")
```

This is the `pages` entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PagesRepository")
*/
class Pages
{
  /**
  * @ORM\Id()
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  private $id;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, unique=true)
  */

  private $unique_id;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */

  private $name;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $template;



  /**
  * @var \Icons
  *
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icons")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $icon;

  public function getIcon(): ?Icons
  {
    return $this->icon;
  }

  public function setIcon(?Icons $icon): self
  {
    $this->icon = $icon;

    return $this;
  }






  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $slug;

  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }




  public function setUniqueId(string $unique_id): self
  {
    $this->unique_id = $unique_id;

    return $this;
  }


  public function getUniqueId(): ?string
  {
    return $this->unique_id;
  }




  public function setUnique_id(string $unique_id): self
  {
    $this->unique_id = $unique_id;

    return $this;
  }

  public function getUnique_id(): ?string
  {
    return $this->unique_id;
  }




  public function getName(): ?string
  {
    return $this->name;
  }



  public function setName(string $name): self
  {
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
  }

  public function getTemplate(): ?string
  {
    return $this->template;
  }

  public function setTemplate(string $template): self
  {
    $this->template = $template;

    return $this;
  }



  public function getSlug(): ?string
  {
    return $this->slug;
  }

  public function setSlug(string $slug): self
  {
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
  }
}
```

In my Controller I call it via Doctrine:

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
```

The output is:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => Pages {#6356 ▶}
  1 => Pages {#6401 ▶}
  2 => Pages {#6402 ▶}
  3 => Pages {#6403 ▶}
  4 => Pages {#6404 ▼
    -id: 5
    -unique_id: "90c29507fd"
    -name: "Felder"
    -template: ""
    -icon: Icons {#6396 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: true
      -id: 1
      -name: "adjust"
       …2
     …2}
    -slug: "fields"
  }
]
```

But what I need is this output:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => Pages {#6356 ▶}
  1 => Pages {#6401 ▶}
  2 => Pages {#6402 ▶}
  3 => Pages {#6403 ▶}
  4 => Pages {#6404 ▼
    -id: 5
    -unique_id: "90c29507fd"
    -name: "Felder"
    -template: ""
    -icon: "adjust"
    -slug: "fields"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how the Doctrine ORM works by nature.

You could add an `__toString` method to `Icons` entity. 
This way you would be able to echo out 
in twig using `` {{ page.icon }}` and not ``{{ page.icon.name }}`

Does that help?

What is your problem having an Icon "instance" ?

Comment: Thank you, but I am really cofused, that it is so difficult to relate just two tables by id. It was so easy in PDO with join left. But with ORM I just cannot get it work

Comment: The ORM is an abstraction of all the JOIN and SQL stuff. Maybe look into Custom Hydration? Hydration is the process that creates objects from the SQL results.

Comment: What is your problem having an Icon object?

Comment: Well, I am creating a json file and there I do not need the object. I need a string, I am also creating a form from the entity, which also only works if icon is a simple string

Comment: Is it not possible to use this:   `/**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icons")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $icon;`

Comment: and then `public function getIcon(): ?string
  {
    return $this->icon;
  }`

Comment: For the form the correct way would be use of the EntityType::class field type. That does all the conversation you need between the Icon Id and the Object (DataTransformer) 

When you are exporting to a "file" in json format the json encodig should be done on an export class on the fly.

Comment: Sure it is possbile exactly that way. That would be "best practise"

Comment: Ok, if I do it exactly that way, I get an error message: `Return value of App\Entity\Pages::getIcon() must be of the type string or null, object returned`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184874/discussion-between-mblaettermann-and-jarla).